# Length of object (3) does not match with length of fields (1) Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting problem with below code. I want to create a single column dataframe.
May I know what wrong I am doing here.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,ArrayType,StructType,StructField,StringType data = [ (["James","Jon","Jane"]), (["Miken","Mik","Mike"]), (["John","Johns"])]
cols = StructType([ StructField("Name",ArrayType(StringType()),True)  ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=cols)
df.printSchema()
df.show()

output:
Name
["James","Jon","Jane"]
["Miken","Mik","Mike"]
["John","Johns"]
```

I am getting a error below.
Length of object (3) does not match with length of fields (1)

Comment: You can check the solution code for get desired output. Cheers!

Comment: from dataclasses import dataclass
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

# Define the connection string function
def con_string(account_name, account_key):
    connection_string = f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    return connection_string

@dataclass
class AzureBlobUploader:
    connection_string: str
    container_name: str

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you added data in form of a `multiple-column structure` and your requirement is in single-column data value.

So for get data in single column values you need to `[(row,) for row in data]`:

```
data = [(["James","Jon","Jane"]), (["Miken","Mik","Mike"]), (["John","Johns"])]
cols = StructType([ StructField("Name",ArrayType(StringType()),True)  ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(row,) for row in data], schema=cols)
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to create arraytype column with different length of elements.

Comment: Its a grouping values as a arraytype in each row of dataframe.

Comment: code edited to groupby data into row

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark has this problem. The way I go about is introduce and ID column, drop it ones the df is created

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,ArrayType,StructType,StructField,StringType

```
data = [ (1,["James","Jon","Jane"]), (2,["Miken","Mik","Mike"]), (3,["John","Johns"])]

cols = StructType([ StructField("ID",IntegerType(),True), StructField("Name",ArrayType(StringType()),True)  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=cols).drop('ID')
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```